# Python Variables with number in name in a loop

Tags: python, arrays

I want to concatenate some matrices a1,a2,a3,a4,... so that I get new matrices which are b1=a1+a2, b2= a2+a3, b3=a3+a4, but I can't think of a way to call the matrices a1,a2,a3,a4... in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add all the matrices to a list:

```
lst_matrices = [a1, a2, a3, a4]
```

To store the results, you should have another list:

```
lst_concatenated_matrices = []
```

And loop over the list:

```
for i in range(len(lst_matrices) - 1):
    matrix_1 = lst_matrices[i]
    matrix_2 = lst_matrices[i + 1]
    lst_concatenated_matrices.append(matrix_1 + matrix_2)
```